# How to upload xml files to FTP Server by using CFNetwork concept in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cfnetwork, ftp-server

How to upload xml files to FTP Server by using CFNetwork concept in iphone?

Is there any sample project?

Is there any openSource available?

Answer (score 1):

There's a dedicated documentation for this problem: [CFNetwork Programming Guide - Working with FTP Servers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Networking/Conceptual/CFNetwork/CFFTPTasks/CFFTPTasks.html).

Try to be more specific if you have any particular issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a library: [SCRFTPRequest](https://github.com/Hackmodford/SCRFTPRequest)

You can also check my little example https://dl.dropbox.com/u/19438780/FTPtest.zip

Comment: Hi TonyMkenu.....I am also using SCRFTPRequest .I successfully created directory and uploaded images to ftp server. The problem which now i am facing is to download the images from ftp server. I you can help ,it would be great.Thanks